# How to detect connection pool issues in Hangfire?

Tags: c#, hangfire, sqlclient

We are seeing the following errors from Hangfire in our logs from time to time:

> Execution BackgroundServerProcess is still in the Failed state for 1.12:52:00.6668371 due to an exception, will be retried no more than in 00:00:15
> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached. at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.CreateAndOpenConnection() at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection[T](DbConnection dedicatedConnection, Func`2 func) at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundServerProcess.CreateServer(BackgroundServerContext context) at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundServerProcess.Execute(Guid executionId, BackgroundExecution execution, CancellationToken stoppingToken, CancellationToken stoppedToken, CancellationToken shutdownToken) at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundProcessingServer.RunServer(Guid executionId, Object state) at Hangfire.Processing.BackgroundExecution.Run(Action`2 callback, Object state)

It seems like we are maxing out the number of connections in the SQL Connection pool.

I would like to to detect this somehow and clear out the pool.  How do I detect it?  Can I use Job Filters for this?

Comment: Are you disposing all connection objects with `using`? It's very unusual to have this problem if you do that, unless you are hammering thousands of queries (and then you probably have other issues)

Comment: Yes, we are disposing.  This is running in a service and we are seeing this only during very heavy load.

Comment: Still sounds strange, are you sure you don't have a leak somewhere? Perhaps you should just increase the pool size. But I would investigate why there are so many concurrent queries being run, maybe you can implement some caching strategy

Comment: What do you mean by "heavy load" ? I Agree with @Charlieface, most of the time, pool depletion is the sign of a code issue. If all your stacktraces are the same, I would say that you are trying to start too many servers (you should only be needing one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version of Hangfire seems to have fixed this issue.